# Product of decreasing function and concave function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I know that a function $f_1(x)$ is concave and another function $f_2(x)$ is decreasing over some $a<x<b$. I want to know is it possible for the product $f_1(x)f_2(x)$ to have two local optimal points in $a<x<b$. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The functions take positive values for $a<x<b$.

Comment: I think we can not say nothing exact here.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg assuming that $x_1<x_2$ and further assuming that $f_1(x_1)f_2(x_1)>f_1(x_2)f_2(x_2)$ then I think for any $x_3>x_2>x_1$ we may be able to say that there can not be two optimal points since the function has taken smaller steps with respect to the steps they have taken over previous increments in $x$. I am assuming that $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are positive funcitons

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg please give me some example so that I can understand the problem better

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is there any formal proof that I can show that there can be more than one optimal points

Comment: For positive functions it's interesting enough.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg you mean that it may be possible to prove that there is only one optimal point?\

Comment: The positivity is necessary to constrain the problem, for instance $f(x)=1-x^2$ and $g(x)=-x$ then $fg$ has a local min and a local max in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @zwim what do you mean by "The positivity is necessary to constrain the problem" please explain. Further your $g(x)$ can attain negative values over $0 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: yes, if we allow $g$ to be negative, it is easy to find examples with at least two local optimum. since you apparently seek for only 1 optimum, it seems legit to force positivity of the functions (i.e. more constraints on f,g).

Comment: @zwim so we can conclude that in the case when functions are positive then there can be only one optimal point in $a<x<b$?

Comment: @zwim thank you for your prompt response. My function linearly decreases (like $1-x$) so I think the region over which your red curve is constant will not exist in my case. Since the red function does not decrease over a certain values of $x$. I think then your example is slightly off.

Comment: @zwim maybe we can see it by shrinking the region over which the function is constant

Comment: @zwim And a local min, so $3$ local extrema in all. That's a good (counter)example.

Comment: @zwim thank you. If the function linearly decreases like $1-x$ then we will have a product of a concave function and a linear function, Right. Then in that case what will be the product? Can we say that it is a concave function. Because I assume that a linear function is both concave and convex.

Answer (score 3):

I propose the following example.

$f_1(x)=4-x^2$ it is an inverted parabola thus concave.

$f_2(x)=2-x^3$ since $f'(x)=-3x^2$ this function is $\searrow$.

Both functions are positive over $[-2,b]$ with $1<b<2$ but we don't care too much about the value, $[-2,1]$ is a good interval.

Here is the graph of $f_1,f_2$ and the product :  http://tiny.cc/p64jpy

[image]

There are $2$ local maxima and a local minimum for the product in $[-2,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

$f_1(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is concave and positive over $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $f_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\sin x}}$ is positive and decreasing, since $\frac{d}{dx}(x+\sin x)=1+\cos x\geq 0$. On the other hand,

$$ f_1(x)\,f_2(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sin x}{x}}} $$
has **an infinity** of stationary points over $\mathbb{R}^+$, since the same holds for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, which is bounded by $1$ in absolute value.