# Does the product of an exponential decrease with a polynomial with positive coefficients have a unique maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Consider a function of the form
$$f(x)=\exp(-x)p(x)$$
where $p$ is a polynomial with exclusively **positive** coefficients. Is it true that $f$ has a unique maximum? It seems like it when playing with functions like this using a graphing calculator. And intuitively the exponential has the longest "spoolup time" but once it starts decreasing faster than the polynomial increases it only ever gets worse.

But I can not prove it. Even nicer would be an explicit representation of this maximum. The first order condition
$$
0 = f'(x) = \exp(-x)[p'(x) - p(x)]
$$

would require $p(x) = p'(x)$. Although this does not look like it should not have a unique solution...

Comment: I am assuming that we are looking at x > 0?

Comment: If you don't require that $x$ is positive then counterexamples exist but they're annoying to write down (I think the minimum degree of a counterexample is $4$, maybe $6$ to be safe). Are you requiring that $x$ is positive?

Comment: $(x^3+1)e^{-x}$ has two local maxima, we can possibly make them both equal by changing to $x^3+a$ for some $a$. Or do you assume also $x>0$ ?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yeah I want $x$ to be positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two counter-examples with $2$ local maxima on $\mathbb R^+$, that I found playing around with the coefficients, and trying to keep the polynomial as simple as possible (I focused on $x^n+ax+b$)

$p(x)=10x^3+21x+18$

$q(x)=x^5+40x+20$

[image]

The positivity constraint makes it a bit difficult to reverse engineer something like "let solve $p'-p=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)$ so that the derivative has many critical points".

Note that the condition on coefficients positivity implies that $p\nearrow$ on $\mathbb R^+$ and since $p(0)\ge 0$ then except maybe in zero, $p$ has not root on $\mathbb R^+$. Therefore the oscillations we see on $p(x)e^{-x}$ results only from the compared growth of the two components and not from $p(x)$ own oscillations.

Comment: Note: I found back another old question which shows that the product of two well behaved functions can nevertheless have more critical points than expected https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2572665/399263

Comment: huh interesting - the polynomials I am interested in have the additional property that they do not have a shift. But I thought that the shift should not have an influence. Curiously though removing the 18 in your first example does result in just one maximum. But the second one also works without the shift by 20... curious

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Take $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$
p_a(x)=(x-a)^2+2(x-a)+2=x^2+2(1-a)x+1+(1-a)%2.
$$
All the coefficients of $p_a$ are positive provided $a<1$.

Now, define
$$
f(x)=p_a(x)e^{-x}, \quad a<1.
$$

Then
$$
f' (x)=-(x-a)^2e^{-x},\quad f''(x)=[(x-a)^2-2(x-a)]e^{-x}.
$$

Thanks to the first derivative test, we know that $f$
is decreasing on $(-\infty,a)$ and on $(a,\infty)$.

Because $f''(x)<0=f''(a)=f''(2)$ for $a<x<2 $ and $f''(x)>0$ for $x<a$ or $x>2$, we know that $f$ has an inflection point at $x=a$.

Thus $f$ has no maximum at all.

Comment: Ok, but the OP is considering only polynomials with positive coefficients.  Can you ensure that $(x-a)^2+2(x-a)+2$ has positive coefficients?

Comment: we need $a<1$ for that which is not too much of a constraint, but I agree it should be added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another class of functions of this form which have no maximum:
Note that
$$e^xf'(x) = (p'-p)(x) = (a_1-a_0)+(2a_2-a_1)x+ \cdots +(na_n-a_{n-1})x^{n-1}-a_nx^n.$$
So, for $f'(x') = 0$, the polynomial on the RHS must equal zero at $x'$.  If we take $a_0 = a_1$, $a_2 = a_1/2,\dots$, then $(p'-p)(x) = -a_nx^n$.
Of course, this will not equal zero unless $x' = 0$.  But $x'=0$ is not a maximum unless $n = 1$.  So, for all $n \geq 2$, no maximum exists.