# Show that there is exactly one $x\in(0,1)$ s.t. $f(x) + x f'(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that
$f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable, $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, $f(0)=f(1)=0$,
and there is exactly one $x\in(0,1)$ s.t. $f'(x)=0$.

Can I show that there is exactly one $x\in(0,1)$ s.t. $f(x) + x f'(x)=0$?

I can't figure out how, although it seems to be true. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Find $(xf(x))'$. Then you can finish the rest

Comment: The expression $f(x) + xf'(x)$ appears in the title, but not the body. Can you double-check the question?

Comment: The title is incomplete, such that what exactly (I suppose it is  $=0$)? Also the question should not rely on what(s written in the title, it should appear explicitly in the question area.

Comment: I changed it accordingly. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the suspicion that the conclusion is not correct! To make the counter example simpler I took the interval$[-1,1]$ instead of $[0,1]$. This is not a loss of generality because we can transfer the function horizontally. And change the exponent appropriately.

Consider the function $f(x)=-e^{-1/2}+e^-\frac{x^{2}}{2}$. It is easy to see that $f(-1)=f(1)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\,(-1,1)$. The graph is like a bell.

Also $f$ is differentiable with derivative $f'(x)=-xe^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}$ and the only point where $f'(x)=0$ is $x=0$.

Now we consider $f(x)+xf'(x)=-e^{-1/2}+e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}(1-x^{2})$.

But this has two real roots in $(-1,1)$ as we can see in the picture (by Wolfram)

[image]

and those are see picture:

[image]

where W(.) is the product log Lambert function!

I have not yet managed to find an appropriate counterexample for the given problem, but I am almost sure there is one!

Answer (score 2):

Applying the same technique (playing with polynomial coefficients) I used in this question revolving around a similar theme

[Does the product of an exponential decrease with a polynomial with positive coefficients have a unique maximum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4487056/399263)

here is a counter example $f(x)=(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)x(1-x)e^{-x^2}$

with $a=4,\ b=-7.78,\ c=3.287$

were $f(x)+xf'(x)=0$ has $3$ roots in $(0,1)$ while the other conditions are respected:

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/co3jq7qetm

The compared growth of polynomials and decreasing exponential often allows to generate more critical points than the intuition can expect, provided you tune the coefficients appropriately.

I agree this is not the most nicest looking function, but the method is source of numerous counter-examples.

Comment: Excellent! I was trying to transform my counterexample on $[0,1]$ but I couldn't. Well Done !